# Installing plugins for all users and on multiple servers

Tags: qgis, installation, plugins

I'm running QGIS on a set of high powered terminal server for our students. I want to install a set of plugins for all users on all the servers, making the plugin manager a bit sluggish to use.

Is there a way I can install plugins for all users?

- Is there a command line option for the plugin manager?
- Is there a folder where I can unpack zip-files so that all users get the plugins on start?

Comment: Mirror a Virtual Machine with QGIS and plugins installed.

Comment: Terminal servers are all in full swing with lots of users and software, so that's not an option.